# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/ksoap2/SoapEnvelope.class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ksoap2

Encounter problem when I'm trying to migrate my old Eclipse project to Android Studio 2. I got the following error message:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
> >     org/ksoap2/SoapEnvelope.class

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myorg.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.2-jar-with-dependencies_timeout1.jar')
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-j2se-full-2.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/PayPal_MPL.jar')
}
```

Don't quite understand what does those errors mean. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: i think that error generally occurs when you have duplicate of same library

Comment: Press ctrl+shift+R and input 'SoapEnvelope'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is you are using two jar files which contains same classes.

[ksoap2-j2se-full-2.1.2.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/k/Downloadksoap2j2sefull212jar.htm)

[ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.2-jar-with-dependencies_timeout1.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/k/Downloadksoap2androidassembly252jarwithdependenciesjar.htm)

both jar contains most of the same classes. better approch is use the single jar file instead using multiple jar which containes similar classes.

```
compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.2-jar-with-dependencies_timeout1.jar')
compile files('libs/ksoap2-j2se-full-2.1.2.jar')
```

Let me know if anything

Comment: Remove `libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.2-jar-with-dependencies_timeout1.jar`. Got a new error message: 

**Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded**

Comment: Fixed it by create a file called `gradle.properties` and add the following line in it:
`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m`

Comment: @ZhouHao if possible thn please update the answer here so other can follow this if needed.